# Calculate the p-value of the testse) In terms of this test, determine the 99% confidence interval for the probability of cure $ω$

Tags: probability

Two people are suffering from a novel viral disease. Both are treated with a drug that has not yet been approved. Both get well again. On the basis of this observation, we would like to make statements about the probability ω with which a person who is ill and treated with this drug gets well again. For this purpose we test the null hypothesis $H_0 : ω = ω_0$ against the alternative hypothesis $H_A : ω > ω_0$

a) Describe in a sentence the test statistic X.

b) How is X distributed among H0?

c) What value of X was observed?

d) Calculate the p-value of the testse) In terms of this test, determine the 99% confidence interval for the probability of cure $ω$

My solution:

a) is simple

b) $ Bin(2,w_0)$

c) $x_b = 2$

d) P-value $= P(x \geq 2) = P(x=2) = \cdots = w^2_0$

e) my idea: $\alpha = 1 \%$

$P(x \geq 2) > 0,5 \, \, \, $ or $\, \, \, P(x \leq 2) > 0,5$

$w^2_0 > 0,5 \, \, \, $ or $\, \, \, 1 > 0,5$

its correct? Thank you :)